# Why does MySQL ignore index in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-indexes, secondary-indexes

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `sms` (
  `sms_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sms_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sms_number` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `sms_text` text,
  `sms_status` int(3) DEFAULT '0',
  `sms_last_tm` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `sms_csinteve_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sms_handler_user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sms_id`),
  KEY `sms_number` (`sms_number`),
  KEY `sms_last_tm` (`sms_last_tm`),
  KEY `sms_csinteve_id` (`sms_csinteve_id`),
  KEY `sms_handler_user_id` (`sms_handler_user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`sms` has more that `2,000,000` rows.

And the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer_service_interaction_events` (
  `csinteve_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `csinteve_interaction_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `csinteve_datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`csinteve_id`),
  KEY `csinteve_interaction_id` (`csinteve_interaction_id`),
  KEY `csinteve_datetime` (`csinteve_datetime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21153 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

with `20,000` rows.

Then this query:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(csinteve_id) as interactions_number
FROM customer_service_interaction_events
JOIN sms
    ON csinteve_id = sms_csinteve_id
WHERE csinteve_interaction_id = 3085
AND sms_handler_user_id = 0;
```

says that:

```
{
    "data":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "select_type": "SIMPLE",
            "table": "customer_service_interaction_events",
            "partitions": null,
            "type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,csinteve_interaction_id",
            "key": "csinteve_interaction_id",
            "key_len": "4",
            "ref": "const",
            "rows": 1,
            "filtered": 100,
            "Extra": "Using index"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "select_type": "SIMPLE",
            "table": "sms",
            "partitions": null,
            "type": "ALL",
            "possible_keys": "sms_csinteve_id,sms_handler_user_id",
            "key": null,
            "key_len": null,
            "ref": null,
            "rows": 2083577,
            "filtered": 99.4,
            "Extra": "Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)"
        }
    ]
}
```

says that for the `sms` table MySQL doesn't use any index (type `ALL`).
Whereas, the `sms` table has an index on the `sms_csinteve_id` column which is in the join with the `customer_service_interaction_events` and  that `customer_service_interaction_events` table has an index on `csinteve_interaction_id`.

The goal of the query is to return the count of unhandled SMSs (`sms`), each one is bound to a customer service event (`customer_service_interaction_events`) and several customer service events have the same interaction id (`customer_service_interaction_events.csinteve_interaction_id`, in the example `3085`).

Thank you.

EDIT:

I tried to add Akina's indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON customer_service_interaction_events (csinteve_interaction_id, csinteve_id);
CREATE INDEX idx ON sms (sms_handler_user_id, sms_csinteve_id);
```

But the EXPLAIN:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT COUNT(csinteve_id) as interactions_number
FROM customer_service_interaction_events
JOIN sms
    ON csinteve_id = sms_csinteve_id
WHERE csinteve_interaction_id = 3085
AND sms_handler_user_id = 0;
```

Still outputs type `ALL` for the `sms`:

```
{
    "data":
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "select_type": "SIMPLE",
            "table": "customer_service_interaction_events",
            "partitions": null,
            "type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": "PRIMARY,csinteve_interaction_id,csinteve_interaction_id__csinteve_id",
            "key": "csinteve_interaction_id",
            "key_len": "4",
            "ref": "const",
            "rows": 1,
            "filtered": 100,
            "Extra": "Using index"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "select_type": "SIMPLE",
            "table": "sms",
            "partitions": null,
            "type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": "sms_csinteve_id,sms_handler_user_id,sms_csinteve_id_2,sms_handler_user_id_2,sms_csinteve_id_3,sms_handler_user_id_3,sms_csinteve_id_4,sms_handler_user_id_4,sms_handler_user_id__sms_csinteve_id",
            "key": "sms_handler_user_id__sms_csinteve_id",
            "key_len": "8",
            "ref": "const,local_bluelinks.customer_service_interaction_events.csinteve_id",
            "rows": 2083577,
            "filtered": 100,
            "Extra": "Using index"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Test this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON customer_service_interaction_events (csinteve_interaction_id, csinteve_id);
CREATE INDEX idx ON sms (sms_handler_user_id, sms_csinteve_id);
```

Comment: That didn't work, I still see `"rows": 1786395,` and `type: ALL` after adding the index you mention.

Comment: @tonix What percent of total table rows amount matches `csinteve_interaction_id = 3085`? `sms_handler_user_id = 0`?

Comment: Only a few records for which `csinteve_interaction_id = 3085` and `csinteve_id = sms_csinteve_id`, but there are many rows for which `sms_handler_user_id = 0`, the only thing is that I am only interested in the rows where `sms_handler_user_id = 0` but for which `csinteve_interaction_id = 3085` and `csinteve_id = sms_csinteve_id` 'cause these two conditions are the ones that I was thinking should narrow the query to a small set of rows to check. Any other idea on how I can boost this query and why does MySQL uses type `ALL` for `sms` even though I JOIN with `csinteve_id = sms_csinteve_id`?

Comment: @tonix *Only a few records for which csinteve_interaction_id = 3085* If so then the first index in my answer must be effective. *there are many rows for which sms_handler_user_id = 0* If so then 2nd index in my answer is not effective, and the index by `sms_csinteve_id` is suitable.

Comment: Yes, I guess so too, but even after adding these indexes, MySQL still doesn't use them for some reason. What could be the issue?

Comment: Please, check my EDIT.

Comment: @tonix Your plan shows that the server selects wrong tables scanning order. Try to swap the tables and use `FROM sms JOIN customer_service_interaction_events`. If the plan will not be altered then add `STRAIGHT_JOIN`.

Comment: Hi @Akina, thank you. Even if after adding the order of the tables and `STRAIGHT_JOIN` I still see `type: ALL` and `"rows": 2083577,` :'(